# Connect lxc network with local network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows, lxc, lxd

My current environment is following; in Windows 10 I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in Hyper-V, this hosted Ubuntu is connected to local network 10.10.10.*, where Ubuntu's IP is 10.10.10.1 and Windows's 10.10.10.100. They see each other and all is good. Inside Ubuntu, I have LXC/LXD containers (nginx, postgres and nodejs service) and for these containers I have bridged network called chyrrybr0 with addresses 10.10.0.*, so current environment look like this:

[image]

I'm able to ping Windows from containers, but I'm not able to ping or connect to containers from Windows. So, my question is following: how can I **add a new network interface to containers**, so I'll be able to setup static IP addresses to 10.10.10.*?

I'm trying to create a network, what's looks like this:

[image]

EDIT: I was able to add new eth1 interface. At first, in Ubuntu host I'd run `lxc network attach eth1 postgres eth1` and then in postgres container I'd added network interface configuration `10-win-network.cfg` with content

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.10.10.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

But, from now, I'm not able to ping Windows host at 10.10.10.100 (`100% packet loss`) and also Ubuntu host at 10.10.10.1 (`icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`). But ping at 10.10.0.249 (IP address of Ubuntu host at cherrybr0) is succesful. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were able to solve this, but I ran into a similar problem lately ("how to access containers which run on my local laptop, from outside of my laptop?"), and I simply added static routes to my home router...

Steps:

- run all your containers on a separate network, for example `172.18.0.0/16`.  All those containers will be behind an IP like `172.18.0.1`, let's call this machine `Ship` (because it has containers..hehe).
- Your `Ship` **also** must have a local ip like `192.168.1.xxx`, which is the address your router knows it for.
- on your router (or windows machine, if that's your router), add a static route for `172.18.0.0` net submask `255.255.0.0` to your `Ship`s  `192.168.1.xxx`.

and voila, now you can call your containers (`172.18.0.xxx`)from anywhere on your local network (including your windows machines)